# Cmd in UBOOT is using physical address?

Tags: memory, u-boot

I'm looking at the cmd_mem.c in UBOOT. When it runs the memory tests, it just asks the user to provide the address (or use the default value) and then it starts to read and write at that address. So does that mean UBOOT cmds are all running on physical memory address? Or it just means it is testing virtual address...?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems your understanding of virtual address concepts needs work. Virtual addresses can be directly mapped to physical address. What platform are you using? In ARM, it uses the MMU. In the event that the MMU is off, ARM (and u-boot) uses 1:1 mapping of virtual and physical addresses. Yes there are MMU-less ARM processors, but I haven't checked lately if the current u-boot still supports those. In PowerPC, it has TLBs.

Comment: My experience is that uboot normally runs either with the MMU disabled or configured so that for RAM, virtual address always equals physical address. Therefore, if you access address 0x100000, you are accessing physical memory at 0x100000.

Comment: That means the tests are testing the correct physical address by luck...Even though it is probably the case...Thanks

Answer (score 2):

U-boot does not implement virtual addresses.

So the range you specify for memory testing are physical addresses.
In U-boot environment you are dealing with linear addresses as they exactly are.

If the MMU isn't configured completely as the OS does, it will simply use the addresses as physical addresses, which u-boot will do.

Thus if you are testing a range say 0x1000-0x2000, it will literally test those physical addresses.